# NoOptionalInterpolation Pod Error Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

[image: For Some odd reason I am receiving this error!]

For some reason, I am now all of a sudden getting this error with Xcode 8.3.2 on the NoOptionalInterpolation Pod. I have tried the following:

1. Deleting Pod files
2. Reinstalling Cocoapods
3. Pod Update
4. Pod Install

Still receiving some odd build error. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Here is the PodFile as requested:
[image]

Comment: Please update your question with your `Podfile`.

Comment: @Hemang Added in the Podfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [version 4.0.0](https://github.com/T-Pham/NoOptionalInterpolation) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to bellow step

clean buid folder. follow bellow step

1. long press alter key and you can select “product” menu then choose “clean build folder” option

   2. hold down alt key and 
      reinstall pod and restart xcode